# Datalist word order

Tags: javascript, html, html-datalist

Lets say you have a simple input field with a data-list attached to it.

```
<input list="suggestions>
<datalist id="suggestions">
   <option value="Apple Pie"></option>
   <option value="Strawberry Cake"></option>
</datalist>
```

When typing "Apple Pie" the hint gets show as expected. But when I change the text in the input field to "Pie Apple" nothing shows.

Is there a way to make it show the Apple Pie option whenever I enter the words in a different order?

Comment: You'll need to either create new options for every permutation of words, or use JavaScript.

Comment: @RickHitchcock Well the end result should be Apple Pie, so creating multiple wont do any good. however I would be interested in seeing how you could achieve this with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pure JavaScript solution, which simulates `datalist` functionality using a `select` element.

```js
var inp= document.querySelector('input'),
    sel= document.querySelector('select');

inp.addEventListener('input', change);
inp.addEventListener('focus', change);
inp.addEventListener('blur', function() {this.value= sel.value;});
sel.addEventListener('change', function() {inp.value= this.value;});

inp.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if(e.which === 40) {  //down arrow
    sel.selectedIndex = Math.min(sel.selectedIndex+1, sel.options.length-1);
    this.value= sel.value;
  }
  else if(e.which === 38) { //up arrow
    sel.selectedIndex = Math.max(sel.selectedIndex-1, 0);
    this.value= sel.value;
  }
});

function change() {
  var options= ['Apple Pie', 'Apple Streudel', 'Blackberry Cobbler', 'Strawberry Cake', 'Banana Pudding'],
      words= inp.value.toLowerCase().trim().split(' '),
      match,
      s= '';

  options.forEach(function(o) {
    match= true;
    words.forEach(function(w) {
      if(w > '' && 
         o.toLowerCase().indexOf(w) !== 0 && 
         o.toLowerCase().indexOf(' '+w) === -1) {
        match= false;
      }
    });
    if(match) {
      s+= '<option>'+o;
    }
  });
  sel.innerHTML= s;
  sel.size= sel.options.length;
}

inp.focus();
```

```css
input, select {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 13px arial;\
}

input:focus + select, select:focus {
  display: block;
}

select {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<select></select>
```